# How to troubleshoot an xcopy crash

Tags: windows-xp, crash, dvd

I'm trying to copy a recording I made on Canon DC320 to my computer but I keep crashing with the message `The parameter is invalid`.  I've done some troubleshooting using Process Monitor and xcopy and determined the following:

- The crash happens at `311,033,856 bytes` every time
- `xcopy` retries 3 times automatically (I assume this is standard)
- Buffer size is `65,536 bytes`
- Starting from `257,949,696`, every read operation happens twice, the second time with `Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O` set as I/O flags
- Windows XP SP3
- DVD-RW 1.4 GB (Sony)
- Recorded on a Canon DC320 in high def
- UDF file system
- Tried with the same results on a Windows 7 computer

Here's the stack trace from the failing `ReadFile` command

```
"Frame","Module","Location","Address","Path"
"0","fltmgr.sys","fltmgr.sys + 0x1888","0xf73cf888","C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\fltmgr.sys"
"1","fltmgr.sys","fltmgr.sys + 0x32a0","0xf73d12a0","C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\fltmgr.sys"
"2","fltmgr.sys","fltmgr.sys + 0x3c48","0xf73d1c48","C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\fltmgr.sys"
"3","fltmgr.sys","fltmgr.sys + 0x4059","0xf73d2059","C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\fltmgr.sys"
"4","ntkrnlpa.exe","ntkrnlpa.exe + 0x181e9","0x804ef1e9","C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe"
"5","ntkrnlpa.exe","ntkrnlpa.exe + 0x18c09","0x804efc09","C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe"
"6","ntkrnlpa.exe","ntkrnlpa.exe + 0x3f734","0x80516734","C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe"
"7","ntkrnlpa.exe","ntkrnlpa.exe + 0x492bd","0x805202bd","C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe"
"8","ntkrnlpa.exe","ntkrnlpa.exe + 0x44541","0x8051b541","C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe"
"9","ntkrnlpa.exe","ntkrnlpa.exe + 0x926dc","0x805696dc","C:\WINDOWS\system32 \ntkrnlpa.exe"
"10","ntkrnlpa.exe","ntkrnlpa.exe + 0x95807","0x8056c807","C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe"
"11","fltmgr.sys","fltmgr.sys + 0x3018","0xf73d1018","C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\fltmgr.sys"
"12","fltmgr.sys","fltmgr.sys + 0x31e4","0xf73d11e4","C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\fltmgr.sys"
"13","fltmgr.sys","fltmgr.sys + 0xeabc","0xf73dcabc","C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\fltmgr.sys"
"14","aswMon2.SYS","aswMon2.SYS + 0x6d86","0xa9dedd86","C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\aswMon2.SYS"
"15","ntkrnlpa.exe","ntkrnlpa.exe + 0xa576c","0x8057c76c","C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe"
"16","ntkrnlpa.exe","ntkrnlpa.exe + 0x6a6cc","0x805416cc","C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe"
"17","kernel32.dll","kernel32.dll + 0x29f4b","0x7c829f4b","C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll"
"18","kernel32.dll","kernel32.dll + 0x2912d","0x7c82912d","C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll"
"19","kernel32.dll","kernel32.dll + 0x217d0","0x7c8217d0","C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll"
"20","ulib.dll","ulib.dll + 0x6da3","0x71fa6da3","C:\WINDOWS\system32\ulib.dll"
"21","xcopy.exe","xcopy.exe + 0x4938","0x1004938","C:\WINDOWS\system32\xcopy.exe"
"22","xcopy.exe","xcopy.exe + 0x511b","0x100511b","C:\WINDOWS\system32\xcopy.exe"
"23","xcopy.exe","xcopy.exe + 0x5d34","0x1005d34","C:\WINDOWS\system32\xcopy.exe"
"24","xcopy.exe","xcopy.exe + 0x5ff7","0x1005ff7","C:\WINDOWS\system32\xcopy.exe"
"25","xcopy.exe","xcopy.exe + 0x6314","0x1006314","C:\WINDOWS\system32\xcopy.exe"
"26","kernel32.dll","kernel32.dll + 0x1776f","0x7c81776f","C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll"
```

Comment: Does it only crash with XCOPY? I mean, if you use MOVE, or a 'normal'  copy and paste, does the same issue occur? Also, what does Event Viewer say?

Comment: You could try performing the copy using [TeraCopy](http://teracopy.com), it lists all the files it tries to copy along with any associated error messages that show up in the process.

Comment: @DaveRook I only started using XCOPY in the first place because I got this error with a copy and paste (in Windows Explorer)

Comment: Also see [How can I copy files from a DVD skipping corrupt files?](http://superuser.com/questions/508679/how-can-i-copy-files-from-a-dvd-skipping-corrupt-files)

Answer (score 0):

It appears your DVD cannot be read at the offending location. Is it scratched. Have you tried cleaning the surface or using another DVD drive to read it.

Comment: I checked the disk, it does not look like it has a scratch.  I can play the video in the camcorder fine, so I don't think it's a scratch.