# Can't copy video from DVD

Tags: windows-7, video, dvd

I have a video in a .MOD file format burned to a DVD.  The video appears to play fine from Windows Media Player and others.  When attempting to copy the video file off of the DVD, windows explorer freezes with a red progress bar.  I tried tera copy (i'm looking for a free utility of course) and that froze.  I've tried making an ISO of the disk, Poweriso encounters the error and offers to skip the cyclic redundancy check but still freezes.  I would give up if it weren't for the fact that I can see the movie play just fine! So how do I recover this corrupted file, or file from a corrupted media?

Comment: See [How can I copy files from a scratched CD/DVD?](http://superuser.com/questions/508679/how-can-i-copy-files-from-a-scratched-cd-dvd) for some things you can try.

Answer (score 2):

Download [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/).  Following the [guide](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/HandBrakeGuide), you should be able to rip the movie from the DVD to a file on your hard drive.  You can save the video file in either MP4 or MKV format.

NOTE: Please follow local laws and regulations when using this utility.

Comment: Are you sure HandBrake supports [.MOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOD_and_TOD) as an input format?

Comment: @Karan I'm not sure, I have not used it (to my knowledge) on a .MOD file.

Comment: @Karan According to http://www.moviecodec.com/encoding/converting-mod-files-to-avi-mpeg-or-wmv-18620/7, it will support .MOD

Comment: Didn't find it mentioned on a quick scan of the HandBrake docs, but maybe I missed it. Anyway, going by the Wikipedia description, either the camcorder must have burnt it to disc directly, or the OP did. In either case I don't think copy-protection of any kind is involved, as on a commercial video DVD. The requirement doesn't seem to be for video DVD ripping and conversion.

Comment: @Karan Very good point on the copy-protection, but these utilities always come under scrutiny.

Comment: Handbrake sort of worked.  It got to where the video was corrupted and recovered up until that point.  At least I'm narrowing down on the point of corruption.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Format Factory](http://www.pcfreetime.com/index.html). It's free and works great. It can convert just about anything.

**EDIT**: Sorry, I misread your question. Since you are able to watch the video, I would suggest using [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html) to stream and save the video. It will take as long as the duration of the video, but it might be your only option.

1. Open **VLC**
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
3. Click **Disk**
4. Make sure your DVD is selected then hit **Convert/Save**
5. Choose your destination file
6. Select your conversion format (if you want to convert it) or select **Dump raw input**
7. Just let it play out

I don't have any corrupt DVDs to try it on, but hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: Copying data from the disc results in CRC errors. I don't see how suggestions for HandBrake and Format Factory are useful given  corrupted files or corrupted media.

Comment: Peter I'm not looking for conversion here, I'm looking for recovery.